# Java getID - Two values?

Tags: java

I can't get my head around this at the moment so any help would be great..

```
for(EdgeOf e: gra.getEachVertex()) {
     System.out.println(e.getId());
}
```

From this I get a result of `41_1`, `32_2` but I want to split these values up and reuse them. I can't seem to pull these values without getting the them both together..?

How can i `string.split` this?

Comment: use `"41_2".split("_")` or `e.getId().split("_")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At 1st iteration e.getId() returns 41_1, so u can split it as 41 and 1 by using split("_"), do the same in 2nd iteration also..

```
for(EdgeOf e: gra.getEachVertex()) {
String str = e.getId();
String[] str2 = str.split("_");
     System.out.println(str2[0] + " " + str2[1]);
}
```

Comment: for(EdgeOf e: gra.getEachVertex()) {
String str = e.getId();
String[] str2 = str.split(_)
     System.out.println(str2[0] + " " + str2[1]);
}

Thanks, this works.

Comment: sorry mr.mipe34! i missed semicolon. `String[] str2 = str.split(_);` now it will compile.

Comment: +1 and corrected it for you, except missing semicolon mr. @Gunaseelan! :-), there was missing quotes `"_"` on split regex.

Answer (score 1):

Try use `string.split()`:

```
for(EdgeOf e: gra.getEachVertex()) {
     String[] values = e.getId().split("_");
     String x = values[0];
     String y = values[1];
}
```